# Logging loss while training in Flux using callbacks

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, julia

I'm trying to write a callback for the `train!` function in Flux.
My code is:

```
cb_loss = x -> push!(x, loss(x_train, y_train))
loss_vector = Vector{Float32}()

Flux.train!(loss, ps, train_data, opt, cb=cb_loss(loss_vector))
```

It gives me this error:

```
MethodError: objects of type Float32 are not callable

Stacktrace:
 [1] call(::Float32) at C:\Users\arjur\.julia\packages\Flux\Fj3bt\src\optimise\train.jl:36
 [2] foreach at .\abstractarray.jl:1920 [inlined]
 [3] #10 at C:\Users\arjur\.julia\packages\Flux\Fj3bt\src\optimise\train.jl:38 [inlined]
 [4] macro expansion at C:\Users\arjur\.julia\packages\Flux\Fj3bt\src\optimise\train.jl:93 [inlined]
 [5] macro expansion at C:\Users\arjur\.julia\packages\Juno\oLB1d\src\progress.jl:134 [inlined]
 [6] #train!#12(::Array{Float32,1}, ::typeof(Flux.Optimise.train!), ::typeof(loss), ::Zygote.Params, ::DataLoader, ::Descent) at C:\Users\arjur\.julia\packages\Flux\Fj3bt\src\optimise\train.jl:81
 [7] (::Flux.Optimise.var"#kw##train!")(::NamedTuple{(:cb,),Tuple{Array{Float32,1}}}, ::typeof(Flux.Optimise.train!), ::Function, ::Zygote.Params, ::DataLoader, ::Descent) at .\none:0
 [8] top-level scope at In[108]:1
```

Interestingly it properly adds the first value to the vector and then crashes so I guess the error message is related to that.

I checked the function outside the `train!` function and it works so how should I rewrite this function to log the loss in a vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you need to pass it like this: `cb=callback`. So it can be done either using global variables or defining the callback like this:

```
loss_vector = Vector{Float32}()
callback() = push!(loss_vector, loss(x_train, y_train))

Flux.train!(loss, ps, train_data, opt, cb=callback)
```